# how to use cp to copy a file to to a file named the same as one directory name in a directory?

Tags: linux, unix, cp

*I am a linux beginner, and today I have a question. I have searched it on the internet,but not solved.*
**suppose there is a file named 1 and a directory named 2, if i want to copy the file1 and make the new file named 2, how can i accomplish it user the command cp ?**

```
mypc:testcp RVFU98$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 RVFU98  staff   0 Aug 27 11:14 1
drwxr-xr-x  2 RVFU98  staff  68 Aug 27 11:13 2
mypc:testcp RVFU98$ cp 1 2
mypc:testcp RVFU98$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 RVFU98  staff    0 Aug 27 11:14 1
drwxr-xr-x  3 RVFU98  staff  102 Aug 27 11:14 2
mypc:testcp RVFU98$ cd 2
mypc:2 RVFU98$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 RVFU98  staff  0 Aug 27 11:14 1
```

i know it is because the new file's name is the same as an existing directory,but i don't know how to solve it ,can any one help me?

Comment: In what directory do you want this new file `2` to reside?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick the testcp directory

Comment: You cannot do that. There can be only one File or one directory with a name not both. Other option is create a file in lowercase and directory in uppercase.  `touch myfile ; mkdir MYFILE`

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: @Beta just a test

Comment: @KaushikNayak thant you,now i get it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy a file over an existing directory. If you know 2 exists and is a directory, you could use this to remove it and replace it with 1:

```
rm -rf 2 && cp 1 2
```

Comment: IMO it's better use `rmdir` to not accidentally clobber a whole tree. There also `find ... -delete` if you want to ensure that only things matching certain criteria get deleted.